# Raising a “warning” status during SDL Tridion 2011 publishing

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We would like to implement some functionality so that when for some reason an error occurs during publishing or resolving, and we skip over it using a try/catch block, but would still like to notify the user that something was skipped.

The SDL Tridion 2011 Publishing Queue can filter by status. One of these statuses is “Warning”. Is it possible to trigger a publish transaction to have a “Warning” status using the API in either template code or a custom resolver?

Comment: Chris. The PublishTransaction class has a settable state property. Have you tried using that? What were the results?

Comment: I have not tried doing this in a Template - My current challenge is trying to do it in a Resolver, and I don't think the PublishTransaction is available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible, but the answers above might help you find an alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is a warning during the publishing (such that the Publish Transaction has status warning), then you will need to set `PublishInstruction.MaximumNumberOfRenderFailures` to something greater than 0. As long as the number of Render errors is lower than the max you specified, the status of the Publish will be Warning.

If an error occurs outside rendering, then the instruction will show as Failed.

On the other hand, if you want to show a message in the GUI (in the MessageCenter) with the 'Warning' that something went wrong, then you will need a more complex architecture. Frank worked on this a while back. The idea (IIRC) is to have a GUI piece, e.g. an iframe polling a service that returns statuses for that user's Publish actions. An event system would produce these statuses by monitoring the PublishInstruction, and it would write them into some kind of storage (file, db, memory) that the service would then poll.

Comment: So how do I raise the error when I catch it? Can this only be done in template code? Any thoughts on  whether this can be done in a Custom Resolver?

Comment: In template code, you wouldn't catch it at all. Let it be thrown and it will count as 1 render failure. It is however trickier if you catch an exception in a customer Resolver. You need to 'defer' the throwing of the error to the template code. You need some mechanism to let the template code know that it should throw an exception. Maybe use AppData on the Component or Page? E.g. Custom Resolver catches exception, writes AppData, then continues and template code executes and first thing it does is to read AppData looking for that flag. If found, throw exception from template code.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai - Unfortunately, that's not going to work with my resolver. When items fail in the resolver they end up not getting added to the package, so they never get rendered (an as such a template is not executed for them). It seems that there is no way for a Custom Resolver to gracefully fail whilst notifying the user in the Publish Queue.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe it's just a matter of putting AppData on a different item (e.g. current User), then read it in template code. But indeed, if your resolver doesn't resolve _anything_ then there is no rendering taking place at all. Maybe you can consider the other approach (a variation of Frank's publish status monitor and MessageCenter)

Comment: I don't think you should use AppData for this, it is meant as additional data on an item, not to store the state of a certain action. That being said, I think there indeed isn't a way to make a renderer fail gracefully, it is meant to work or fail completely. When it fails the process should be halted by means of the exception. If you are catching errors in the renderer and want it to continue, then the only option you have is to log a warning but that will never make it back to the publish transaction unfortunately.