# How to get resourceName for Tridion LocalizableMessage when creating new PublisherException?

Tags: tridion

I need to stop publishing of a page when a certain condition exists, for example if the page name contains 'one' using the Event System.  Also, the other pages should continue to publish.

I am thinking to use a PublisherException instead of a generic exception.

The problem is the I do not know the resourceName of the LocalizableMessage.  Any ideas?

```
if (item.Title.ToString().Contains("one"))
{
     Localization.LocalizableMessage errResource = new Localization.LocalizableMessage("error");
     throw new PublisherException(errResource, new Exception("Can't get there from here!"));
}
```

Comment: Apart from LocalizableMessage question, isn't a custom resolver a better fit for this task?

Comment: I guess you are saying I can remove the item from the PublishTransaction if it meets the conditions?  Is it possible for a Custom Resolver's error message to appear in the Publish Queue?  Any other ideas for passing feedback to the user the item is not published?  In this example I am attempting to send the Page to an external web service and when the external service fails to not publish it.

Comment: Are you using R5.3? I see you reference that in a comment below

Comment: Upgrading from a 5.3 RenderPre event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Event System can stop Publishing, there is no middle ground there though, when you throw an exception, it stops the entire transaction.

Like Puntero mentions, if you want to remove an item from a Publish Transaction, that is where a [Custom Resolver](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_753C261063AD4B9CA5E4F50BD4FD48E9) comes in. From here you cannot communicate back to the Publish Transaction, but you have access to the Tridion Logger (eventlog):

```cs
Tridion.Logging.Logger.Write("your message string", "MyResolver", LoggingCategory.General, TraceEventType.Information);
```

With regards to your LocalizableMessage in the Event System, you should be able to do the following:

```cs
throw new PublisherException(new LocalizableMessage(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager, "PagePublishErrorMessage"));
```

Where the resourceName is pointing to the name of a String resource you have in your Project.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion to use the Tridion logger.  I might use a SignalR GUI extension to pass the info to the user in the MessageCenter as well.  But, I still prefer the OnRenderPre event in 5.3 and using an exception to fail a single item and have the exception message in the publish queue.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Puntero that if you want other page in a publish action to go through, you should use a Resolver rather than an Event Handler.

I tried to raise a warning to alert users of one item not being resolved, but failed. But there may be some good tips/ideas for you here: [Raising a “warning” status during SDL Tridion 2011 publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894802/raising-a-warning-status-during-sdl-tridion-2011-publishing)

In the end, the only way I could get anything to work was to set "Allow X failures", and then do a check in a template, and raise the error there. That will count as a Render failure, and allow the publisher to move on to the next item in the publish transaction.

As for the message? What message would you like to display?

Comment: Very interesting!  If I understand correctly, you raise the exception in the custom resolver and then check for that exception in the Template? What does the check in the template look like?

Comment: Well that is what I tried to do, but couldn't do it without misusing AppData or something. So we just ended up throwing the error in the template.